# How to disable when mouse is over a button it's making the button control size grow?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In the screenshot the button in the left at runtime before the mouse is over the button.

The same button on the right is when the mouse is over the button then there is some black border around the button that make it looks like the button size get a bit growing. This is what i want to disable.

I found now that even if i change the color to transparent the button control size still grow when the mouse is over the button.

```
<Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
```

Changed it from Black to Transparent but it didn't help.

[image: Button at runtime]

I created a new folder in the Solution Explorer name : ResourceDictionaries
And inside the folder created a file name Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="4,2" 
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                        CornerRadius="3" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then updated the App.xaml file :

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score -1):

Working solution :

In the file Dictionary1.xaml deleting the line :

```
<Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
```

Between the Trigger tags did the job.